# str_replace for shortcode purposes

Tags: php, html, parsing

Not really sure how to describe this, but I'll try my best. I'm trying to replicate a shortcode like structure for replacing a string within a certain container of text. Kind of like how Wordpress operates shortcodes.

For example `[text str="hello world" class="text"]` would output as `<p class="text">hello world</p>`.

Here's what I have so far with my exploration,

```
<?php

$text = "[hello]";

$String = str_replace(array('[hello]'),array('Hi there!'),$text);
echo $String;

?>
```

I'm replacing text based on a specific string. How could I be more specific and call upon something like `[text str="hello world" class="text"]` and have it output like this `<p class="text">hello world</p>`?

Comment: you will need to break content of your short code into multiple elements. in this case you will break `[text str="hello world" class="text"]` into `text`,`str="hello world"`,`class="text"`. Then you will probably need to create a function with default arguments that accepts all of that input. example (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: Have you looked at how WordPress [does it](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions,  for example:

```
$find = [
    '~\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]~s',
    '~\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/size\]~s'
];

$replace = [
    '<b>$1</b>',
    '<span style="font-size:$1px;">$2</span>'
];

$text = preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
```